# Why we use query.toLowerCase() in this code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to understand the second `toLowerCase` .Here is the code.

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange'];

function filterItems(query) {
  return fruits.filter(function(el) {
    return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  })
}

console.log(filterItems('ap')); // ['apple', 'grapes']
```

Answer (score 4):

The function compares two strings case-insensitive, so let's say `Abc` and `abC`.
The first `.toLowerCase` lowers `Abc` to `abc`, the second one lowers `abC` to `abc`.

As a result, you can successfully compare both with each other which could not be done without any of the two.

EDIT: To be precise, the "indexOf"-Method internally compares two vaues for which the equal casing is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Because the programmer expects the input to not be uniform in its cases and the comparison they are doing is case-sensitive. Converting everything to lower case helps them compare without getting errors like `Apple != apple`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
 var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange'];
 function filterItems(query) {   return fruits.filter(function(el) {
       return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1;   }) }
 
 console.log(filterItems('AP')); // ['apple', 'grapes']
```

Without the toLowerCase u r not getting the result what u have expected . indexOf function checks with **caseSensitive**.so, we need to change the both querystring and searchString to same sensitive strings. so , that we are using **toLowerCase()** there.

Comment: Yes , because indexOf using caseSensitive for finding the index of the query string.but here the query string and the array value are different like apple not equal to APPLE

Answer (score 0):

#### Case Insesitive

It makes the function [case-insesitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity) in the snippet below I have removed the second `toLowerCase()` and made the first letter of the query uppercase as you can see the result set will be empty

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange'];

function filterItems(query) {
  return fruits.filter(function(el) {
    return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1;
  })
}

console.log(filterItems('Ap')); // ['Apple', 'grapes']
```

The reason is it will make the first element of fruits `toLowerCase()`(which is already) but in case it would be *AppLe* -> *apple* and compares with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) *IndexOf returns the position of the first occurence* if the string *Ap* occurs in the calling string which is not the case.

But with the second `toLowerCase()` it is indeed the case.

#### Bottom Line

The [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) function will make every letter as the name says lowercase like *AbAbcbsAbA* ->  *ababcbsaba*

So the first `toLowerCase()` makes every fruit like *Apple* or *Bannana*  to *apple* *banana* and the second makes the query like *Ap* to *ap*.

This leads to that filterItems is case-insesitive.

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange'];

function filterItems(query) {
  return fruits.filter(function(el) {
    return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  })
}

console.log(filterItems('Ap')); // ['Apple', 'grapes']
```